# Null Pointer Exception SD Card Folder has no Photo

Tags: android, android-activity

How to show Toast if list has no Photo, i am making an app in which allowing user to take pic and storing that pic into specific folder, which created automatically,

Whenever I do click on View button, if user has taken screens then its showing me those photos in a List, and if user has not taken any pic then getting Exception, so here i want to show a Toast Message if user has not captured any pic.

**Logcat:**

```
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.UploadActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.example.UploadActivity.getSD(UploadActivity.java:125)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.example.UploadActivity.onCreate(UploadActivity.java:106)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-22 06:48:28.248: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  ... 11 more
```

**SingleAngelActivity.java:**

```
  Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    Log.d(SingleAngelActivity.LOG_TAG, "captureButton :: " + captureButton);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            Log.d(SingleAngelActivity.LOG_TAG, "mCamera.takePicture :: " + mCamera);                                            
        }
    });

    Button viewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
    Log.d(SingleAngelActivity.LOG_TAG, "SingleAngelActivityButton :: " + viewButton);
    viewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            Intent intentNewEvent = new Intent(SingleAngelActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentNewEvent);                  
        }
    });
```

**UploadActivity.java:**

```
private List <String> getSD()
        {
            List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();

            String string = "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/MyNewImages/";
            File f = new File (string+ SingleAngelActivity.customFolder+ "/");

            Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "KEY_TITLE :::--- " + f);
            File[] files = f.listFiles ();
            Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "getListImages() :::--- " + files);

            for (int i = 0; i <files.length; i++)           
            {
                File  file = files[i];
                Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "i<files.length() :::--- " + i);
                Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
                it.add (file.getPath());
            }
            Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "List <String> it :::--- " + it);
            return it;
        }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of `getSd()`.  Step through it in the debugger.  What's null?

Comment: You have to check is card is mounted first. I guess this line `File[] files = f.listFiles ();` ends up in `files` being null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works only if the SD card is mounted, the path is correct and no other problems. It just checks whether the folder have any files or not

try the following code

```
private List <String> getSD()
    {
        List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();

        String string = "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/MyNewImages/";
        File f = new File (string+ SingleAngelActivity.customFolder+ "/");

        Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "KEY_TITLE :::--- " + f);
        File[] files = f.listFiles ();
        Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "getListImages() :::--- " + files);
        if(files == null)
         Toast.MakeText(this,"No photo",700).show();
        else
        for (int i = 0; i <files.length; i++)           
        {
            File  file = files[i];
            Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "i<files.length() :::--- " + i);
            Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
            it.add (file.getPath());
        }
        Log.d(UploadActivity.LOG_TAG, "List <String> it :::--- " + it);
        return it;
    }
```

Comment: This one will probably give you NPE in this line "if(files.length == 0)".

Comment: How does checking if `files` has any items help with NPE?

Comment: still facing same problem

Comment: Just replace "if(files.length == 0)" with "if(files == null)" and it's done. :)

Comment: @ChiralCode thanks for help, i have accepted as answer and checked as useful